# How do I select every other div class element using just CSS (no js)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know how to do this using javascript and php, but I am trying to learn how/if it is possible to do this using just css.

I have a container which holds many items.  Each item has a picture, and below it, a div containing a description.  I want the background of the description to be different for every other item.

Is it possible to achieve this using just css? If so, how?  I have been fooling around with using the selectors

```
.item:nth-child(odd){background-color:red}
.item .description:nth-of-type(odd){background-color:orange;}
```

I can't seem to get it.  Suggestions, comments, anything is appreciated.
Below is some simplified sample code that demonstrates what I have going on.

```
<style>
#container{width:100% height:100%;}
.item {float:left; width:250px; height:700px;}
.item img {width:250px; height:250px; float:left;}
.description {width:250px; height:450px; float:left; background-color:blue;}
.description:nth-of-type(even){background-color:red;}      // <- Here's the line!!
</style>

<html>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div class="item">       //item 1
    <img src="image.jpg"/>
    <div class="description"> //This (and every odd number) I want to be blue 
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <h2>Sub Title</h2>
     <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit for Adun!</p>
     <a href="#">::LEARN MORE::</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">      //item 2 and so on...
    <img src="image.jpg"/>
    <div class="description"> //and this (and every even number, red)
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <h2>Sub Title</h2>
     <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit for Adun!</p>
     <a href="#">::LEARN MORE::</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You want `nth-child()` on `.item`.

```
.item:nth-child(odd) .description {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Awesome cats, haha

Comment: This does not work. You cannot select nth-child by class, only by element type. If you add another div with another class the odds and evens will all shift.

Comment: I agree with @WalturBuerk. I've tried this and was perplexed at inconsistent results only to realize sometimes I had a sibling with a different class that was counted in this pseudo selector. Bummer.

Answer (score 10):

```
.item:nth-child(even) {...}
.item:nth-child(odd) {...}
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DuL24/1/**

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's possible when we use this:

```
.item:nth-of-type(odd)  .description{background-color:orange;}
```

or

```
.item:nth-child(odd) .description{background-color:orange;}
```

You can see my screenshots: http://screencast.com/t/17g9joVj8Z
I hope you get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you should set nth-of-type to .item element:

```
#container{width:100% height:100%;}
.item {float:left; width:250px; height:700px;}
.item img {width:250px; height:250px; float:left;}
.description {width:250px; height:450px; float:left; background-color:blue;}
.item:nth-of-type(even) .description {background-color:red;}
```