# Style for loop with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

Im supposed to make 8 boxes and style them each, make the boxes with for loop. Every odd box should look different then the others. I have tried to make an id, but when i use the id in CSS, it wont do anything. Can someone help?

Here is the code i have:

```js
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  text += "Box number " + i + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.demo {
  border: black;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This is question for JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: You can probably try out straight CSS with `:nth-child(odd)` to color odd elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: `.demo` selects all elements that have `class="demo"`. For `id="demo"` you need `#demo`. You'll also want to create eight elements (your code creates 9 text nodes). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2cd98n3L/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select every other div class element using just CSS (no js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986810/how-do-i-select-every-other-div-class-element-using-just-css-no-js)

Comment: You can not “style a for loop”, that makes no sense. You are not creating any “boxes” right now, you are outputting pure text. So, start by making your loop output an HTML element for each item.

Comment: you're not outputting any elements to style:::: text += "<div>Box number " + i + "</div>"; then use the #demo:nth-child(odd) selector as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

As volodymyr says use `css` nth-child property.

In javascript you can accomplish this in the following manner:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.class').length; i += 2){
  document.querySelectorAll('.class')[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
   <div class="class">1</div>
    <div class="class">2</div>
    <div class="class">3</div>
    <div class="class">4</div>
    <div class="class">5</div>
    <div class="class">6</div>
    <div class="class">7</div>
    <div class="class">8</div>
    <div class="class">9</div>
    <div class="class">10</div>
```

This uses a for loop which iterates over every odd element, and then applies styles via javascript. Usually a pure CSS implementation would be preferable though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css nth-clild property

```css
.class:nth-child(odd) {background: red}
```

```html
    <div class="class">1</div>
    <div class="class">2</div>
    <div class="class">3</div>
    <div class="class">4</div>
    <div class="class">5</div>
    <div class="class">6</div>
    <div class="class">7</div>
    <div class="class">8</div>
    <div class="class">9</div>
    <div class="class">10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css references the "class" demo selector but your HTML uses an "id" property id='demo'. Change either one to match the other.