# Making cards with javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am supposed to make 9 cards. Use a for loop to create t.
When it says it is number 1, that should increment by the number that it is in the loop.
Add the number of the loop to a data attribute.
Create a CSS class for the card that gives it the styling of the image above.
Every odd card should have a background color of #52ce90.
The color of the text should change to white.

I have tried, but i cant figure out how to do it.

Here is my code:

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
var newCard = "test";
var i;
for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  newCard += "Box number" + i "<br>";
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="Container">
  <div class="card" id="card">
    <div class="card--header">
      <h1 class="card--number--text">
        Card number
      </h1>

      </div>
      <div class="card--by">
        By 
      </div>
      <div class="card--time">
       43 minutes ago
      </div>
      <button class="card--button"> View on site</button>
```

And how to style in css, what class or id should i use, and how to get the boxes up?

Comment: do you need something like adding a card when the button is clicked?

Comment: No, the button is going to be "fake"

Comment: So, you want to generate 9 cards using JS with styles right?

Comment: Yeah, i think so. But i think i should style them with CSS, so i just need to get the setup right, so i can begin to style. It is the setup with Html and JS i am struggling on

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738238/style-for-loop-with-css // Even if you increased the number from 8 to 9 now, doesn’t make this a fundamentally different question - so you should stick with your existing one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style for loop with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738238/style-for-loop-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a snippet that match your requirements. See it here:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
for( var i=1;i <=9; i++)
{
 var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.className ="card";
  el.id = "card" + i;
  el.innerHTML = "ok";
  container.append(el);
}
```

```css
.card:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #52ce90;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have code that will append card-odd class to odd values. Know you can style it as you wish

```
let container = document.querySelector('.container');

for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    let myDiv = document.createElement("div");
  if (i%2 === 0) {
    myDiv.innerHTML = "<div class=\"card\">"+ i +"</div>" 
  }
  else {
    myDiv.innerHTML = "<div class=\"card card-odd\">"+ i +"</div>" 
  }
    container.appendChild(myDiv);
}
```

here you have a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/06Lnghvw/

Also you can simply style odd and even card using pure CSS. Please read: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp